# ModelMetadata.FromStringExpression doesn't work on nested properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, metadata

I have a complex type in my model with some meta-data;

```
[ComplexType]    
public class ComplexModel
{
    [Display("Name Label")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MainModel
{
    // ...

    public ComplextModel ComplexModel { get; set; }
}
```

This code works correctly;

```
Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ComplexModel.Name)
```

But this one doesn't;

```
Html.Display("ComplexModel.Name")
```

Even I go farther and find out the problem which is `ModelMetadata.FromStringExpression`.

`ModelMetadata.FromStringExpression("ComplexModel.Name", viewData)` returns incorrect result. While `ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, viewData)` works correctly.

Is it a bug?

I just wanted `Html.Display("ComplexModel.Name")` to work correctly and return "Name Label" in this example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new custom HtmlHelper class that uses a new Model or new ViewData, so :

```
public static class CustomHtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static HtmlHelper CustomHtmlHelper(this HtmlHelper helper, Object model)
    {
        ViewDataDictionary customViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(helper.ViewData) { Model = model };
        ViewDataContainer customViewDataContainer = new ViewDataContainer(customViewData);
        ViewContext customViewContext =
            new ViewContext(helper.ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext, helper.ViewContext.View, customViewData, helper.ViewContext.TempData, helper.ViewContext.Writer);

        return new HtmlHelper(customViewContext, customViewDataContainer, helper.RouteCollection);

    }


    private class ViewDataContainer : IViewDataContainer
    {
        public ViewDataDictionary ViewData { get; set; }

        public ViewDataContainer(ViewDataDictionary viewData)
        {
            ViewData = viewData;
        }
    }

}
```

Then you can write your own custom helpers for Display or use the Display helper like this :

```
@Html.CustomHtmlHelper(Model.ComplexModel).Display("Name");
```

And DisplayName for the "Name Lable":

```
@Html.CustomHtmlHelper(Model.ComplexModel).DisplayName("Name);
```

Custom Display method to be used directly with @Html :

```
public static class CustomDisplayHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString CustomDisplay(this HtmlHelper helper, string expression, Object model)
    {
        HtmlHelper customHelper = helper.CustomHtmlHelper(model);
        return customHelper.Display(expression);
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString CustomDisplayName(this HtmlHelper helper, string expression, Object model)
    {
        HtmlHelper customHelper = helper.CustomHtmlHelper(model);
        return customHelper.DisplayName(expression);
    }
}
```

:

```
@Html.CustomDisplay("Name", Model.ComplexModel)
@Html.CustomDisplayName("Name", Model.ComplexModel)
```

If you want to use `ModelMetadata.FromStringExpression` to get the "Name Lable" , the code look like this :

```
ViewDataDictionary myViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(Model.ComplexModel); 
ModelMetadata metadata ModelMetadata.FromStringExpression("Name", MyViewData);
```

And get the display name or any other attributes :

```
String displayName = metadata.DisplayName;
```

Or better way :

```
String displayName = metadata.GetDisplayName;
```